# formatted output like this in python

Tags: python, mysql

Here is the python code with the query to the database

```
cursor.execute("""select count(distinct offering_name) as events
,count(learner) as learners 
,count(distinct learner) as unique_learner
,count(dropped) as dropped
,sum(trans_price) as trans_price
from EMS_data where organization like 'eng%' and manager ='rakesh'""")
```

for result in cursor:
    print result

the result will be like this and what does the "L" means

(367L, 7200L, 4543L, 7200L, 3216157.0)

but i want to like this

| events | learners | unique_learner | dropped | trans_price        |

|    378 |     8092 |           5204 |    8092 | 3197704.0799999996 |

how can do in this way... Please help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an output in `csv` format. And you can get column names from `cursor.description`.

Try this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
    csv.writerow([col[0] for col in cursor.description])
    for result in cursor:
        writer.writerow(result)
```

`test.csv`:

```
events|learners|unique_learner|dropped|trans_price
367|7200|4543|7200|3216157.0
```

Alternatively, instead of using csv module, you can use string formatting as @Mr E suggested, or just join values via `" | ".join(...)`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... well i was reading the csv format file and i'm passing the query to the database.... and i wanted the result like that..